# 1 fluentd instance catches 2 different sets of data, how do i point to different indices?

Tags: fluentd

I have a script that sends HTTP traffic to fluent for processing to elasticsearch.  The URL sample is:  `http://fluentd:24225` and I send some JSON that needs to be processed to it as a post request.

I see in my fluentd conf file which I will paste below will have a match that will send stuff to elastic search.

What I want to do, is to, based on a Parameter in URL or JSON property, would determine a second index in which I could submit, with a different logstash_prefix.

I didn't seem to understand how to update the data accordingly.

```
# fluentd/conf/fluent.conf
<source>
  @type forward
  port 24224
  bind 0.0.0.0
</source>
<source>
  @type http
  port 24225
  bind 0.0.0.0
</source>
<parse>
  @type json
  @time_key date
</parse>
<match *.**>
  @type copy
  <store>
    @type elasticsearch
    host elasticsearch
    port 9200
    logstash_format true
    logstash_prefix fluentd
    logstash_dateformat %Y%m%d
    include_tag_key true
    type_name access_log
    tag_key @log_name
    flush_interval 1s
  </store>
  <store>
    @type stdout
  </store>
</match>
```

So I was looking at the fluentd docs https://docs.fluentd.org/input/http, and I was noticing for the HTTP it was doing: `https://0.0.0.0:9999/app.log` and I was not sure what the app.log correlates to since my app works without it.  I was thinking that maybe I could have my different datasets go to different endpoints: app1.log and app2.log, BUT I wasn't seeing anywhere in the config file for fluentd that configures my data with the correct prefix.   Does the *.** associated in the match, correlate to "app.log"?

I was trying to understand the docks a bit more but I got stumped here.

ideally, if I can send both data sets to this instance of fluentd, and then based on a prop, route it to different indices of the same elastic instances, that would be amazing.

EDIT:
Right now I am rebuilding everything and attempting to add `app1.log` to my post requests, and similarly adding it to my match params to see if this is in fact the way to do it.  The following code I noticed seems to point to it as the correct answer:

```
# Receive events from 24224/tcp
# This is used by log forwarding and the fluent-cat command
<source>
  @type forward
  port 24224
</source>

# http://<ip>:9880/myapp.access?json={"event":"data"}
<source>
  @type http
  port 9880
</source>

# Match events tagged with "myapp.access" and
# store them to /var/log/fluent/access.%Y-%m-%d
# Of course, you can control how you partition your data
# with the time_slice_format option.
<match myapp.access>
  @type file
  path /var/log/fluent/access
</match>
```

Update TBD

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to confirm that yes, you can have the source set stuff, and then the HTTP request endpoint will allow you to organize based on map requirements.

App1:
https://0.0.0.0:24225/app1.log

App2:
https://0.0.0.0:24225/app2.log

Then in the match requirements of the log file::

```
<match app1.log>
 <store>
    @type elasticsearch
    host elasticsearch
    port 9200
    logstash_format true
    logstash_prefix app1          # <---- update prefix
    logstash_dateformat %Y%m%d
    include_tag_key true
    type_name access_log
    tag_key @log_name
    flush_interval 1s
  </store>
  <store>
    @type stdout
  </store>
</match>
<match app2.log>
 <store>
    @type elasticsearch
    host elasticsearch
    port 9200
    logstash_format true
    logstash_prefix app2     # <----- Update Prefix
    logstash_dateformat %Y%m%d
    include_tag_key true
    type_name access_log
    tag_key @log_name
    flush_interval 1s
  </store>
  <store>
    @type stdout
  </store>
</match>
```